# How did IM Gotham discover cheating before the game?

Tags: cheating

In a recent scandal, IM Gotham correctly pointed out a cheat even before the game

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAY_pC3yc0c&ab_channel=JustForFunHD

The video was in a low digital quality so I couldn't see the screen properly. Not sure where to find the original high definition video. How did Gotham find out the person was a cheater instantly?

Answer (score 9):

You can't see it well because it's behind his camera view, but he clicks on the player, bringing up the profile page. And there is his rating chart, which has gone up by a 1000 points in 30 days, very smoothly, as he mentions a few seconds later.

As that would be immediately visible and it's also what he says, my guess is that that is why he immediately suspects cheating.

Then after that, constantly taking more or less the same amount of seconds for every single move, even in the opening, confirms it.